# pass gridview name for printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a working function that prints a grid. I have many grids. In the code below the gridname is hardcoded(code behind).

Can I pass in a gridview name as a paramater when the asp.net button is pressed?

Then I can have one print function that handles all my grids which would be extensible and awesome.

**Markup:**

```
<input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print" onclick="PrintGridData()" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void PrintCurrentPage(object sender, EventArgs e) // Print Current Page
        {

            try
            {


                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                GridViewErrorReport.RenderControl(hw);
                string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
                    .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
                sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
                sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
                sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
                sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
                sb.Append(gridHTML);
                sb.Append("\");");
                sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
                sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
                sb.Append("printWin.print();");
                sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
                sb.Append("</script>");
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());


            }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintGridData() {
        var prtGrid = document.getElementById('<%=GridViewErrorReport.ClientID %>');
        prtGrid.border = 0;
        var prtwin = window.open('', 'PrintGridViewData', 'left=100,top=100,width=1000,height=1000,tollbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1');
        prtwin.document.write(prtGrid.outerHTML);
        prtwin.document.close();
        prtwin.focus();
        prtwin.print();
        prtwin.close();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can pass the id to your function, and use it to retrieve your grid control from the page..

Suppose "myGridId" is passed to function...

Your code should now look like this

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridViewErrorReport.RenderControl(hw);
string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
GridView gv = (GridView)this.FindControl("myGridId");
sb.Append(gv);
sb.Append("\");");
sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
sb.Append("printWin.print();");
sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
sb.Append("</script>");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
```